# How to show user data stored in child firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was tired how to retrieve single data from child in my firebase,  but when using setAuthenticatedUser to retrieve user email it work successfully..

my question how to get my other sigle child like my email to TextView?

this my MainActivity.java after Logged in

```
private void setAuthenticatedUser(AuthData authData) {
    mAuthData = authData;
    if (authData != null) {

        /* User auth has not expire yet */

        // Get unique current user ID
        mCurrentUserUid=authData.getUid();

        // Get current user email
        mCurrentUserEmail= (String) authData.getProviderData().get("email");
        String email = mCurrentUserEmail;
        tvEmail.setText(emails.toString()); // success

        // Get current user Full Name
        mCurrentUserFullname= (String) authData.getProviderData().get("fullName");
        String fName = mCurrentUserFullname;
        tvName.setText(fName.toString()); // aborted

    } else {
        // Token expires or user log out
        // So show logIn screen to reinitiate the token
        navigateToLogin();
    }
}
```

this is my json in firebase
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkIBu.png)

Thankyou for helping me, sorry with my english & keep learning :)